# 405 Method Not allowed for 3d Secure Payment in Edge

Tags: angular, payment-gateway, 3d-secure

I am doing 3d Secure Payment in the application, when we are redirecting back from Payment Gateway to UI via API we are getting 405 Method not allowed in Edge Browser it is working fine in all other browsers.
[image]

I am not sure why this issue is coming is it something to change in Angular Code?
Kindly Suggest

Comment: What HTTP requests are being made by each browser? How do they compare?

Comment: Check if you have the right HTTP request eg. get, post, put, patch, delete, etc.

Comment: They have GET HTTP Request